How to change background color of individual Codemirror element?
In a page showing several Codemirror (Version 5) elements, I would like to change the background color of one of these Codemirrors using Javascript.
The only way to specify the background color that I could find is adding
.CodeMirror {
  background-color: "someColor";
}

to the css style. However, this would change all Codemirror editors together, not a single one.
So I would need to find a possibility to get the DOM element related to the codemirror instance. I managed to achieve this as follows:
cmDiv = textareaSource.nextSibling;
cmDiv.style.backgroundColor = "someColor";

This works, because the Codemirror div is created directly after the textarea from which it was created. However I am not sure if it is safe do assume that this will always be correct.
Is there any safe and documented way to achieve this?
